# Precise Drag and Drop within a contenteditable with dynamic drag(button)

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

Hiii Everyone,

```
         Below is my reference for my project,
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseMoskal/T2zHQ/

I tried like that.What is the issue Im facing is instead of single fancy drag(button) I had created multiple buttons dynamically and Tried to drag Its not working properly.

Instaed of direct addition of class fancy

```
for(i = 1; i <=4; i++) {
     $(".choice").append("<a class='fancy'>Choice1</a>");
  }
```

Add class dynamically using Jquery.If I add like this with above code I can't drag and drop why is it so?Can anyone please help me to get out of this issue.

Below is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/KavyaBabu/T2zHQ/159/

Comment: Are you Initilizing the DragonDrop function after the above code being executed..?

Comment: No @KarthikeyanVedi.. I just call this function once document ready

Comment: If you wish to use jquery draggable https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Answer (score 1):

```js
    $( ".word").draggable({
      revert: "invalid",
      containment: "document",
      helper: "clone",
      cursor: "move"
    });
    
      $('.blank').droppable({
      accept: ".word",
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
      //debugger;
   event.target.innerText = ui.draggable.text();
      $(event.target).effect('highlight');
      }
    });
```

```css
.blank{
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px dashed #FF5722;
    padding: 4px;
    background: rgba(255, 87, 34, 0.2);
    display:inline-block;
    min-width:100px;
    text-align:center;
}
.blank:after{
  content: '\00a0';
}
.word{
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px dashed #4CAF50;
    padding: 2px;
    background: rgba(76, 175, 80, 0.3);
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor:move;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div>
Lorem Ipsum is simply <span class="blank"></span> text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy <span class="blank"></span> ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing  <span class="blank"></span> passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
<hr/>
<div>
  <span class="word" >dummy</span>
  <span class="word" >text</span>
  <span class="word" >Lorem Ipsum</span>  
</div>
```

Check this [Js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KarthikeyanVedi/c62tpc45/)

Make sure that all the `.fancy` elements exists in DOM before initilizing the DragonDrop .

Comment: DRAGON_DROP is not a function error i am getting after used dragula plugin.

Comment: do you have the `function DRAGON_DROP (o)` line in your code.. if you are not using the old dragon drop plugin remove `window.DragonDrop = new DRAGON_DROP({..})` lines from your code

Comment: If I remove that part I can't drag the fancy button @karthikeyan..I had used this part of jquery only http://jsfiddle.net/T2zHQ/169/

Comment: Here did u use dragula plugin or else normal things http://jsfiddle.net/T2zHQ/168/

Comment: @KavyaShree http://jsfiddle.net/T2zHQ/168 is the plugin which you have used... http://jsfiddle.net/T2zHQ/169 is the dragula plugin version

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/T2zHQ/169/ I had tried this..But I can't drop text inside paragraph and in another fiddle same issue only text is dropped

Comment: @KavyaShree Check this http://fillintheblank.quizyplugin.com/ maybe this will help you

Comment: @KavyaShree Check this https://jsfiddle.net/KarthikeyanVedi/c62tpc45/ see answer for snippet